# Align checkbox and two other elements as if they were a line

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-float

I have a form that nowadays looks like this:

[Current Form](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmfaeE/)

Now, I want to add a checkbox and a text that let the user to accepts the terms of the site.  I want this checkbox and the text to be on the left of the "Send button", so here is what I have tried:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" class="accept_form" style="display: block; ">
    <fieldset> 
        <div class="mail_from"> 
            <label for="from">Name</label> 
            <input class="mail" type="text" name="from" id="from"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="mail_to"> 
            <label>Last name</label> 
            <input class="mail" type="text" > 
        </div> 
        <div class="message"> 
            <label>Comment</label> 
            <textarea>I love this page, so I sign up</textarea> 
        </div> 
        <div class = "terms_button">
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "agree">
        <label for = "agree"> Accept the terms </label>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

​
So, basically I have created a new div and inside I tried to align those elements. However, as you can see the checkbox and the text are upper than the Send button.  How can I solve this?

The demo is here: [Not aligned checkbox with Send button](http://jsfiddle.net/ag44K/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: right` from this selector:

```
form .terms_button button {
    float:right;
}
```

Working sample (the only change is removing the `float: right;`)
http://jsfiddle.net/ag44K/22/

Answer (score 0):

the `vertical-align` CSS property is what you are probably looking for, see the [CSS2 specification at W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) for in depth discussion. The trouble starts, I'm afraid, with the label text size being not 100% (of the check-box element) and probably also with the border, padding and font size in the button element - you might be in for some longer tweaking (especially if you want it to scale sensibly on zooming).

Answer (score 0):

Only tip: I take a look to your site and i overview your code, i see that the commit button has Float Right, i believe that adding a new `li` item and set the item float Right it can put the item at the left of the Commit button due you are adding the item after the Commit button. Hope this may help you...